# lost folders cutting pasting to windows

Tags: dual-boot, directory, paste

I was cutting and pasting several folders from Ubuntu to a folder I created in the windows 7 partition on the same computer. I left the computer for an hour or so and it was in standby when i came back to it. The folders I was copying are gone from my home folder in Ubuntu and not in the new folder on windows. I've tried searching rubbish bins and temp folders on both systems, but cant find the missing folders. I`m keeping the computer in standby mode and not shutting down until I find them or give up. Please help, lots of kids photos and work docs I would hate to lose.
kind regards
Rhye

Comment: Using `sudo find / -iname "*partial_file_name*"` search for a name of file you remember. Or, while in Windows "administrator" command prompt change to drive you are supposed to have copied the files and run `DIR \*partial_file_name*.* /s`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. All the file and folder names i tried couldnt be found. Im worried that if i shutdown ubunto to boot into windows i will lise tmp files that may be where my missing ones are?

Comment: You should do `chkdsk` / `fsck` on the disk(s). Probably your computer was not able to flush the disk cache onto disk(s) and you have lost most of your data.